# What can I do about a nuget Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.6.1 missing from my computer, My project will not deploy is a a WebDeploy

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, msbuild, nuget

I am so frustrated, I have an MVC project 4.5, it is a very simple project. I can build it locally, and I can publish it, but when I attempt to do an MSBuild, I receive the following error:

[image]

I checked my Nuget Installed Node, and it was not installed (I must have uninstalled it at this point), but I was having the error when it was installed. In any case, I installed it again, checked my pending changes and did a rebuild:

Now I get a different, but similar error:

[image]

Now, I have checked that the package is installed in my NuGet, it is installed.
My package.config shows the following:

```
 <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.6.1" targetFramework="net45" developmentDependency="true" />
```

I checked the packages folder the "Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.6.1\tools is there as well.

my .csproj file has the following :

```
 <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <!--  <Error Condition="!Exists('packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.7.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.3.7.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.props'))" /> -->
    <!--  <Error Condition="!Exists('packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.6.1\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.6.1\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" /> -->
    <!--  <Error Condition="!Exists('packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.6.1\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.6.1\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" /> -->
    <Error Condition="!Exists('packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.3.6.0\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.3.6.0\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.6.1\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.6.1\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />
    <!--   <Error Condition="!Exists('packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.7.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.7.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" /> -->
    <!--   <Error Condition="!Exists('packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.3.7.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.3.7.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" /> -->
  </Target>
  <Import Project="packag
```

I have tried to delete that selection for the .csproj but it did not make any difference. I just don't understand.

Any assistance would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

So, this issue is resolved. It turns out that the Microsoft.Net.Compiler.2.6.1 requires that your project is running under .NET 4.7.2, our environment and our solutions are all currently on .NET 4.5. This NuGet package is auto-installed when you create a solution in VS2017. Hopefully, this helps others who may run into this issue.